# Changing vertical and horizontal margin in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, margin, facet

I'm producing a facet diagram with ggplot2. I would like to change the margin. I have found that the *panel.margin* argument to *theme()* can be used to change margin size.

```
library(grid)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(vs ~ am)
p <- p + facet_grid(vs ~ am)
p <- p + theme(panel.margin = unit(3, "lines"))
p
```

I would like to change independently the margin size in x (horizontal) or y (vertical) directions. Is there a solution to do that ?

Thank you for helping

Comment: Have you seen `panel.margin.x` and `panel.margin.y`?

Comment: No. I will have a look. Sorry if it was that simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for has been renamed to `panel.spacing`:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(vs ~ am)
p <- p + facet_grid(vs ~ am)
p <- p + theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(1, "lines"),
               panel.spacing.y = unit(3, "lines"))
p
```

[image]